# Python Implementation of ODE for matrix operations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to develop a model and I am stuck as to how this should be implemented in python using ODE. My entire population is divided into regions and part of the model takes this into consideration as provided by the summation below where P is the entire population and each subpopulation is represented by the subscript j=1,2,3...n.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d S_j}{d t}  =-S_j(t) \sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_{j, k} \frac{P_k}{P_j} I_k(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{d I_j}{d t}  =-S_j(t) \sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_{j, k} \frac{P_k}{P_j} I_k(t) - \lambda I_k(t)
\end{equation}

Above are two of the many ODEs in the model. gamma_{j, k} is an adjacency matrix and lambda is a scalar parameter.

To simplify the code, I represented the adjacency and population proportion to J array and explicitly computed the value before passing it to the ODE.

\begin{equation}
J  =  \gamma_{j, k} \frac{P_k}{P_j} 
\end{equation}

```
j = 0
J = beta * gamma_matrix[j] * (P / P[j])

def ode_system(y, t, mu, sigma, delta, lambda):
    
    S,I= y
    dSdt = -S * np.sum(J * I) + mu * (1 - S)
    dIdt = sigma * E + np.exp(-mu * tau) * S * np.sum(J * I) - delta * I - lambda * I - mu * I

    return dSdt, dIdt
```

But my concern is that I_k in the equation means it should be multiplied to all subpopulations value of I hence should be an array. Since the system of ODES is computing for S and I for the jth subpopulation, I am lost as to how I would generate I_k for all subpopulations. Please note that E(t) in the dI_j/dt is also an ODE that is being computed and uses the value of S(t), so I cannot just generate I(t) on its and use it to generate S(t).

Appreciate if you can point me in the right direction